# Adding multiple class names in a ruby link_to tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

```
    <%= link_to 'Certificate Name', certificates_path(:sort => 'name'), id:'name_header', class:@name_header %>
```

I want to use bootstrap to style this link. So I'd like to add multiple class names, but I'm not very sure how to do this as I have used a variable name as a class name. If it was class: 'header' I would have just added the additional class names into the quotes, but I am confused when it is written like this.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options. You can pass an array as the `class:` value:

```
link_to ..., class: [@name_header, 'some-class', 'some-other-class']
```

or you could pass a single string and interpolate `@name_header`:

```
link_to ..., class: "#{@name_header} some-class some-other-class"
```

If I was mixing variables and fixed CSS classes, I'd go with the first approach; if I was just using a fixed list of CSS classes, I'd pass them all as a string. That's just personal preference though.